# Fetching applications, clients, and departments related to a ticket

Tags: javascript, optimization, performance, couchdb

I have a CouchDB view with the following `view/reduce` function. After working over 2 hours on it, I have a result I am happy with, but I believe there is a lot of room for improvement. Basically, I would like the code a bit more slim.

```
map: function (doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'ticket') {
        emit([doc._id, doc.applications, doc.clients, doc.release, doc.departments], doc)
    } else if (doc.type == 'application') {
        emit([doc._id, 0], doc)
    } else if (doc.type == 'client') {
        emit([doc._id, 1], doc)
    } else if (doc.type == 'release') {
        emit([doc._id, 2], doc)
    } else if (doc.type == 'department') {
        emit([doc._id, 3], doc)
    }
}, 
reduce: function (keys, values, rereduce) {
    var result = null
    var applications = []
    var clients = []
    var release
    var departments = []
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i]) {
            if (values[i].type == 'ticket') {
                result = values[i]
            } else if (values[i].type == 'application') {
                applications.push(values[i])
            } else if (values[i].type == 'client') {
                clients.push(values[i])
            } else if (values[i].type == 'release') {
                release = values[i]
            } else if (values[i].type == 'department') {
                departments.push(values[i])
            }
        }
    }
    if (result != null) {
        var apps = []
        var cls = []
        var deps = []
        if (result.applications) {
            for (var i = 0; i < applications.length; i++) {
                if (result.applications.indexOf(applications[i]._id) > -1) {
                    apps.push(applications[i])
                }
            }
        }
        if (result.clients) {
            for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
                if (result.clients.indexOf(clients[i]._id) > -1) {
                    cls.push(clients[i])
                }
            }
        }
        if (result.departments) {
            for (var i = 0; i < departments.length; i++) {
                if (result.departments.indexOf(departments[i]._id) > -1) {
                    deps.push(departments[i])
                }
            }
        }
        result.applications = apps
        result.clients = cls
        result.departments = deps
        result.release = release
        return result
    }
}
}
```

To answer the question, what my code is doing, I have documents in my database, which contain ticket data. These look like this:

```
{
   "_id": "12345",
   "_rev": "33-bb1ad1ec8429b638f1cb8ec2c592c8f6",
   "priority": "200",
   "description": "Ja, ist was",
   "deadline": "",
   "minutesperweek": "125",
   "ordervolume": "125",
   "impactdescription": "Irgendwas geht nicht mehr",
   "applications": [
       "6817eeda32184183e792011df10013e6"
   ],
   "departments": [
       "966f9e33d4d0233d967e0e3d3a000a90"
   ],
   "type": "ticket",
   "assignee": {
       "_id": "theo",
       "firstname": "Theo",
       "lastname": "Test",
       "emailaddress": "theo.test@test.de",
       "phonenumber": "123456"
   },
   "assigneehistory": [
       {
           "_id": "theo",
           "firstname": "Theo",
           "lastname": "Test",
           "emailaddress": "theo.test@test.de",
           "phonenumber": "123456"
       }
   ],
   "comments": [
       {
           "commentvalue": "asd",
           "creator": {
               "_id": "theo",
               "firstname": "Theo",
               "lastname": "Test",
               "emailaddress": "theo.test@test.de",
               "phonenumber": "123456"
           },
           "created": "2014-11-27T15:03:00.342Z"
       }
   ],
   "clients": [
       "1152b87a2c7650ba9f8a7992b10009a1",
       "1152b87a2c7650ba9f8a7992b1000c4e"
   ],
   "reviewcomment": [
       {
           "commentvalue": "fdg",
           "creator": {
               "firstname": "Theo",
               "_id": "test",
               "lastname": "Test",
               "emailaddress": "theo.test@test.de",
               "phonenumber": "123456"
           },
           "created": "2014-12-02T13:50:47.218Z"
       }
   ],
   "reviewed": true
}
```

With the posted `reduce` function I would like to replace the arrays of `clients`, `applications` and `departments` with the items from the database. I think that the `reduce` is not very efficient.

Comment: I am not sure what this does, can you put a blurb in your question?

Comment: Sure, just give me a bit time :)

Answer (score 1):

The mapping function can be a lot simpler, i.e.:

```
map: function (doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'ticket') {
        emit([doc._id, doc.applications, doc.clients, doc.release, doc.departments], doc);
        return;
    }

    var types = ['application', 'client', 'release', 'department'];
    var index = types.indexOf(doc.type);
    if (index != -1)
        emit([doc._id, index], doc);
},
```

The `return` isn't strictly necessary, but it's better to exit early
anyway.

Now for the reducing function you can again make use of a bit of
indirection to reduce the number of lines.  I'd also recommend
[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) or any other functional library to
get rid of the loops, but I guess that is a matter of taste.

I've also always remove as many layers of nesting as possible to
keep the code readable, so by using `return`, `continue`, or `break`
at the earliest convenience.

So kind of like the following:

```
reduce: function (keys, values, rereduce) {
    var result = null;
    var release;

    var sequences = {
        application: [],
        client: [],
        department: []
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var value = values[i];

        if (!value)
            continue;

        var type = value.type;

        if (type == 'ticket')
            result = value;
        else if (type == 'release')
            release = value;
        else {
            var types = ['application', 'client', 'department'];
            var index = types.indexOf(doc.type);
            if (index != -1)
                sequences[type].push(values[i]);
        }
    }

    if (!result)
        return;

    var apps = [];
    var cls = [];
    var deps = [];

    ...
}
```

Comment: I have a question to the part after the `if (!result)` what should go there? I am a little unclear :/ Btw. the map and reduce functions are great :)

Comment: Oh, just what you already had in the result block, didn't want to repeat that part.

Comment: I think I am to silly to use it properly, I get `null` for `key` and `value` in cradle...

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question,

first off, you have a few jshint problems:

- Finish your lines with semicolons
- Declare `i` only once in your function
- Avoid `null`, count on `undefined`
- You are not using `keys`
- You are not using `rereduce`

Beyond this,

- You could generalize the pushing off applications, clients, releases, and departments.
- Instead of using an array with objects with an `_id`, why not collect the `_id` values instead in a lookup object, this would be much faster (reduced lookup time) and use less memory.
- You could generalize the lookups off applications, clients, releases, and departments in the 2nd part of the code.

My counter proposal looks like this:

```
function replaceKeysWithValues(keys, values) {
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        keys[i] = values[keys[i]];
    }
}

function reduce(keys, values, rereduce) {
    var lookups = {
            application: {},
            client: {},
            department: {},
            release: {},
        },
        lookupKeys = Object.keys(lookups),
        result, i;
    for(i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = values[i] || {};
        if(values[i].type == 'ticket') {
            result = values[i];
        } else if(lookupKeys.indexOf(values[i].type) != -1) {
            lookups[values[i].type][values[i]._id] = values[i];
        }
    }
    if(!result) {
        return;
    }
    if(result.applications) {
        replaceKeysWithValues(result.applications, lookups.application);
    }
    if(result.clients) {
        replaceKeysWithValues(result.clients, lookups.client);
    }
    if(result.departments) {
        replaceKeysWithValues(result.departments, lookups.department);
    }
    if(result.releases) {
        replaceKeysWithValues(result.releases, lookups.release);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) `keys` and `rereduce` I have to have. If I use it or not ;) The part with `i` I don't get why and the same goes for the semicolon, I mean JavaScript offers it and I like it :) With `undefined` instead of `null` I come from C# there you have no `undefined` thanks for that hint :)

Comment: Ah, you can write FORTRAN in any language, but if you write JavaScript, you should use semicolons ;) As for using several times `var i`, that does not do what you think it does and it's a waste of characters. Meaning `var i = 3;var i;i;` will evaluate to 3.

Comment: I think the part with semicolons, would go to far :D Because I like it way more without ;) With `i` I understood you wrong ^^ My mistake :) To your code, I could get it run, but it returns `null` for `applications`, `clients` and `departments`

Comment: Gah, I dont have a full test case, but I think I fixed it with `lookups[values[i].type][values[i]._id] = values[i];` Still, do you understand what I tried to do here?

Comment: Yeah I do and I like your approach :) But it seems not to fix it. I gonna go behind it later today. I also checked the part with semicolons again and found that: http://jshint.com/docs/options/#asi

Comment: ;) Check the coding style section on the 2014 JS Developer Survey: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1rZXWof4SJRxhQaQOiEzVQzk_u1KLODNaOer-VGAZDcw/viewanalytics?usp=form_confirm

Comment: At least 6% :P But like I said, that is not the topic here :) But I can actually use the document for another discussion thanks :D

Comment: Ok, I checked the code and worked a bit on it. And it is not working. I tried a bit around with the `log` function and found out, the reduce function gets called 5 times. And all times, it does something different...